# iOS 10 Swift 3 - ViewController inside ScrollView

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swift3, ios10

Trying to put ViewControllers inside a horizontally scrolling ScrollView and I have tried no matter what I do the width of each ViewController is incorrect and can't get each ViewController to be same. The above ScrollView works perfectly fine and is used for paging through UIImageView. The below one is the issue, perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this.

Would appreciate any help on this, code is pasted below for others. Hope it helps.

[image]

```
contentScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Create the three views used in the swipe container view
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let aboutVC: AboutViewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AboutViewController") as! AboutViewController
    let categoriesVC: CategoriesViewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoriesViewController") as! CategoriesViewController
    let reviewsVC: ReviewsViewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReviewsViewController") as! ReviewsViewController

    // Add in each view to the container view hierarchy
    // Add them in opposite order since the view hieracrhy is a stack

    self.addChildViewController(aboutVC)
    self.contentScrollView!.addSubview(aboutVC.view)
    aboutVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.addChildViewController(categoriesVC)
    self.contentScrollView!.addSubview(categoriesVC.view)
    categoriesVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    self.addChildViewController(reviewsVC)
    self.contentScrollView!.addSubview(reviewsVC.view)
    reviewsVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    contentScrollView.bringSubview(toFront: contentScrollView)
    // Set up the frames of the view controllers to align
    // with eachother inside the container view
    print("scroll view frame bounds: \(self.pagerScrollView.frame.width)")
    print("view frame bounds: \(self.view.frame.width)")
    print("screen main bounds: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)")


    let width = self.view.frame.width

    aboutVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: contentScrollView.frame.size.height)
    categoriesVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: width, y: 0, width: width, height: contentScrollView.frame.size.height)
    reviewsVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: 2 * width, y: 0, width: width, height: contentScrollView.frame.size.height)

    // Finally set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames
    self.contentScrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width: 3 * self.pagerScrollView.frame.width, height: contentScrollView.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: You can use Collection view and View Controllers in deed.

Comment: you can use pageviewcontroller.

Comment: pageviewcontroller takes the entire page and that's not the UX I am going for

Comment: I can use collection view but there is already one there, so I am trying to avoid that. I am just stumped to why this issue is happening and already it works perfectly if the scrollview is full screen.

Comment: use container view ..than and in that container you can add pageviewcontroller